# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Craig CLP281 netbook?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-netbook, android

The netbook was sold with Android (2.2) on it.  It only has 4 GB of built in storage.  Is that enough to install a minimal Ubuntu install onto?

If so, how would I go about doing it?

[Here](http://www.craigelectronics.com/site/pdetails.php?id=314) are the specs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it's not possible.  I [asked on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/404459/117307) how to get it to boot from a USB stick and was told that it doesn't boot from the flash memory, only from its firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the how to do:

1. Download ROM R4 from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1392593.
2. Extract wmt_controlscript and firmwareinstall on root of the sdcard.
3. Empty the firmwareinstall folder.
4. Put all the ubuntu.zip with the iso on firmwareinstall folder.
5. Insert sdcard in clp281.
6. Wait for everything to get installed.
7. Here you got what you wanted.

In case of a problem, you can reinstall the original firmware or the rooted one. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the normal ubuntu reqyuires about 6gb, but you can install the ubuntu server, and then install a desktop manager.
Thats how I made a old laptop with a raid of usb sticks work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can. I have this net book and it is hardly able to run android with 256mb of ram. Also Ubuntu runs on an x86 architecture but this netbook runs on ARM and I'm pretty sure Ubuntu can't run on ARM processors, especially not one this slow. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

put ubuntu on firmwareinstall folder, put the folder at sdcard root and HERE YOU GOT MY FRIEND!

Comment: Could you point me at a more detailed guide please?  When you say "put ubuntu" do you mean the .iso image?  If so, which one?  Where do I find the firewareinstall folder?  Etc.

Comment: @ChrisMoore superuser.com is pretty knowledgeable, if they say the device won't boot from flash memory and only from firmware, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @LordofTime That's what I thought too.  But christophe rose seems to maybe know better.  I wanted to see if he really does, because it would be useful to be able to run Ubuntu on the thing if possible.  It looks like he made the account here just to answer my question after all...